# How to send emails from webmail using Amazon Web Services (AWS)?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, email-server

I have currently Rackspace Cloud Server on static range to send mail.

Amazon SES as part of AWS seems to be designed for "bulk and transitional" emailing.

Is there any solution for "regular email"?

AWS IP range is dynamic, hence, it's impossible to send mail from these. Also, it seems that SES is not the correct way of doing it either, or maybe, it is?

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "bulk and transitional emailing" and "regular email" or link to definitions of these terms?

Comment: Here - they mention it in the first line: http://aws.amazon.com/ses/ The regular email is in the opposition to bulk and transactional.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly what _exactly_ you're trying to achieve and why you want to use AWS for it?

Comment: I want to setup a webmail using AWS for business customers, so there are mailboxes, IMAP as well Webmail over HTTPS, virus checker, spam assassin etc, using my own domain name, so I setup SPF and DKIM myself.

Comment: "Regular" email **is** transactional email. Use SES. It'll make you happy.

Comment: Transactional IS NOT regular email. Transactional email is email generated from websites, while regular email is hand-written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have really two ways of solving this:

1. Launch email-server ec2 instance, allocate and assign Elastic IP to it and remove EC2 email limitations by contacting Amazon https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request
2. Buy separate dedicated server/VPS and make VPN tunnel to it from your servers.

I personally prefer the second way and think that AWS is not really suited for emailing even with SES.

Comment: No tunnel was required, I used some ports that were ok to use (over SSL). I used some server in UK (as it's for UK email) and it works just fine as that VPS subnet is clean from spammers.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this: http://support.rightscale.com/09-Clouds/AWS/01-AWS_Basics/How_do_I_send_reliable_email_from_EC2%3F

To send reliable mail you have to setup SMTP server on one of your AWS instances with Elastic IP, request limitations to be disabled and create Reverse DNS record, and other DNS records (SPF, DKIM).

Comment: Well, I thought that SES is not OK for sending business email, but if you say so, I will try it now and see how it works and will let you know here ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend amazon SES for transactional/regular email. Here by transactional I mean 'signup emails for websites', 'receipt emails for e-commerce sites' etc. SES is shared among many users, so abuse by another user might delay/block your legitimate email. Browse the SES forum to see the occurences of such events. If you know how to setup and maintain an email server, stick to your rackspace static IP.